# SharePoint On premises or SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

[image: GET-Spoweb is Not recognized]Is there any possibility to get **SharePoint On Premises** **Cmdlet** Data Using **SharePoint Online** .

Currently I am using SharePoint Online. I want to get data from `Get-Spsite`.

Does `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Online.Sharepoint.Powershell` work in SharePoint Online?

Correct me if  I am doing Wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get data from SharePoint Online using powershell, then You need to use `Get-SPOSite` instead of `Get-Spsite`.

You can get more info about **SharePoint Online Management Shell cmdlets** form [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161388.aspx)

Reference:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362.aspx
- [PDF](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiojJCH8qvNAhXFLo8KHdxOBYgQFggkMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.technet.com%2Fcfs-file.ashx%2F__key%2Ftelligent-evolution-components-attachments%2F01-9981-00-00-03-63-30-65%2FSharePoint-Online-Administration-with-PowerShell.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEauECi8z1rkgXoUzWb__QLmqkQwg&sig2=JylYaOpXPtaMQaS0i8j_Ug&bvm=bv.124272578,d.c2I)
- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161380.aspx

Comment: Thank you . i also want to get the subsite Details  for a Site .
Command for subsite Details is 'get-spsite ' but if i am not wrong it is for On-premises .
is there any command for SpOnline to get subsite details and its users details.

Comment: You can find commands for SharePoint Online in the reference

Comment: You can use Get-SPOWeb -Username trial@trialtrial123.onmicrosoft.com -AdminPassword Pass -Url https://trialtrial123.sharepoint.com    Reference link: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-SPOWeb-to-retrieve-e99b7285

Comment: Thank you . but Get-SPO web is not showing to me int my Powershell.
please find the attachment i am updating image in my question.